# ml.net sentiment analysis warning about format errors & bad values

Tags: c#, visual-studio, ml.net

I've been having a problem with my ml.net console app. This is my first time using ml.net in Visual Studio so I was following [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/machine-learning/tutorials/sentiment-analysis) tutorial from microsoft.com, which is a sentiment analysis using binary classification.

I'm trying to process some test data in the form of tsv files to get a positive or negative sentiment analysis, but in debugging I'm receiving warnings there being 1 format error and 2 bad values.

I decided to ask all you *great* devs here on Stack to see if anyone can help me find a solution.

Here's an image of the debugging below:

[image]

Here's the link to my test data:

[wiki-data](https://github.com/dotnet/machinelearning/blob/master/test/data/wikipedia-detox-250-line-data.tsv)

[wiki-test-data](https://github.com/dotnet/machinelearning/blob/master/test/data/wikipedia-detox-250-line-test.tsv)

Finally, here's my code for those who what to reproduce the problem:

There's 2 c# files: SentimentData.cs & Program.cs.

1 - SentimentData.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using Microsoft.ML.Runtime.Api;

namespace MachineLearningTut
{
 public class SentimentData
 {
    [Column(ordinal: "0")]
    public string SentimentText;
    [Column(ordinal: "1", name: "Label")]
    public float Sentiment;
 }

 public class SentimentPrediction
 {
    [ColumnName("PredictedLabel")]
    public bool Sentiment;
 }
}
```

2 - Program.cs:

```
using System;
using Microsoft.ML.Models;
using Microsoft.ML.Runtime;
using Microsoft.ML.Runtime.Api;
using Microsoft.ML.Trainers;
using Microsoft.ML.Transforms;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using Microsoft.ML;
using Microsoft.ML.Data;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace MachineLearningTut
{
class Program
{
    const string _dataPath = @".\Data\wikipedia-detox-250-line-data.tsv";
    const string _testDataPath = @".\Data\wikipedia-detox-250-line-test.tsv";
    const string _modelpath = @".\Data\Model.zip";

    static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        var model = await TrainAsync();

        Evaluate(model);

        Predict(model);
    }

    public static async Task<PredictionModel<SentimentData, SentimentPrediction>> TrainAsync()
    {
        var pipeline = new LearningPipeline();

        pipeline.Add(new TextLoader (_dataPath).CreateFrom<SentimentData>());

        pipeline.Add(new TextFeaturizer("Features", "SentimentText"));

        pipeline.Add(new FastForestBinaryClassifier() { NumLeaves = 5, NumTrees = 5, MinDocumentsInLeafs = 2 });

        PredictionModel<SentimentData, SentimentPrediction> model = pipeline.Train<SentimentData, SentimentPrediction>();

        await model.WriteAsync(path: _modelpath);

        return model;
    }

    public static void Evaluate(PredictionModel<SentimentData, SentimentPrediction> model)
    {
        var testData = new TextLoader(_testDataPath).CreateFrom<SentimentData>();

        var evaluator = new BinaryClassificationEvaluator();

        BinaryClassificationMetrics metrics = evaluator.Evaluate(model, testData);

        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.WriteLine("PredictionModel quality metrics evaluation");
        Console.WriteLine("-------------------------------------");
        Console.WriteLine($"Accuracy: {metrics.Accuracy:P2}");
        Console.WriteLine($"Auc: {metrics.Auc:P2}");
        Console.WriteLine($"F1Score: {metrics.F1Score:P2}");

    }

    public static void Predict(PredictionModel<SentimentData, SentimentPrediction> model)
    {
        IEnumerable<SentimentData> sentiments = new[]
        {
            new SentimentData
            {
                SentimentText = "Please refrain from adding nonsense to Wikipedia."
            },

            new SentimentData
            {
                SentimentText = "He is the best, and the article should say that."
            }
        };

        IEnumerable<SentimentPrediction> predictions = model.Predict(sentiments);

        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.WriteLine("Sentiment Predictions");
        Console.WriteLine("---------------------");

        var sentimentsAndPredictions = sentiments.Zip(predictions, (sentiment, prediction) => (sentiment, prediction));

        foreach (var item in sentimentsAndPredictions)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Sentiment: {item.sentiment.SentimentText} | Prediction: {(item.prediction.Sentiment ? "Positive" : "Negative")}");
        }
        Console.WriteLine();
    }
}
```

}

If anyone would like to see the code or more details on the solution, ask me on the chat and I'll send it. Thanks in advance!!! [*Throws a Thumbs Up*]

Comment: Welcome to S.O. Check the help section and provide a [mcve]. Please do note that "_it_ _gives_ _me_ _warnings_" is not a detailed description.

Comment: Thanks, should i rewrite the question and make it more detailed?

Comment: imho you should not only provide more info, but also include the minimal code to reproduce your problem, describe what you intend to do and what errors do you have.

Comment: @TheGodofOfficeWork You can just edit the question to add your code :). I think I've seen that issue before where the types were incorrect in the classes that define your input columns of the data or the output for the scores. EDIT: Here's [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50244255/ml-net-bad-value-at-line-1-in-column-label) I saw earlier that looks similar.

Comment: @Jon Gotcha. I'm busy revising the question as we speak. Ill also have a look at that link you put up

Comment: The format error is mentioned in [GitHub](https://github.com/dotnet/machinelearning/blob/master/test/data/wikipedia-detox-250-line-data.tsv): "Unclosed quoted field on line 83".

Comment: @Jon I've removed line 83, which looks like it was a step in the right direction. I'm no longer getting warnings, but the code still goes into break mode after a certain time.

Answer (score 1):

I *think* I got a fix for you. A couple of things to update:

First, I think you got your `SentimentData` properties switched to what the data has. Try changing it to

```
[Column(ordinal: "0", name: "Label")]
public float Sentiment;

[Column(ordinal: "1")]
public string SentimentText;
```

Second, use the `useHeader` parameter in the `TextLoader.CreateFrom` method. Don't forget to add that to the other one for the validation data, as well.

```
pipeline.Add(new TextLoader(_dataPath).CreateFrom<SentimentData>(useHeader: true));
```

With those two updates, I got the below output. Looks like a nice model with an AUC of 85%!

[image]

Comment: I meant to add that I also removed the bad format line.

Comment: That sounds (and looks) like it'll work. Ill try that right now.

Comment: Just one thing I'm unclear on. When you say add the useHeader param to the validator data do you mean the Evaluate method?

Comment: Yep! Otherwise you'll get one instance of a bad value being reported.

Comment: I've changed the SentimentData props, as well as the TextLoaders in TrainAysnc/Evaluate, but in debugging the console still goes into break mode :( .

Comment: I noticed that, too, but it may be a different issue. What was the error it was giving you?

Comment: I think it may be the Evaluate method where things are going wrong. Does your TextLoader.CreateForm in Evaluate look like this: `var testData = new TextLoader(_testDataPath).CreateFrom<SentimentData>(useHeader: true);`

Comment: It still isn't working on my side. I don't like to take short-cuts when it comes to coding, but could you send me your version of the entire code? Maybe there's something i missed on my end?

Comment: Sure! It may be a little while before I can though but I'll definitely get it to you.

Comment: @TheGodofOfficeWork Here's a gist of what I have that's working - https://gist.github.com/jwood803/e23ce879fcc4a5d8e294d930bb0fb848. I did remove the line that saves the model, though, in case that turns out to be the issue.

Comment: I'm starting to strongly believe that it may be a problem with my machine or how I've set up my Visual Studio. I'm planning on testing this out on my friends machine to confirm. Many thanks Jon, Id up-vote your answer if I had the rep [Throws a double thumbs up]

Comment: Glad to help, @TheGodofOfficeWork! Feel free to let me know if I can help further with this. Keep in mind that ML.NET is still very early in preview so weird issues are bound to happen :p

Answer (score 0):

Another thing that helps with text type datasets is indicating that the text has quotes:

```
TextLoader("someFile.txt").CreateFrom<Input>(useHeader: true, allowQuotedStrings: true)
```

Comment: I've tried adding that property to allow quoted strings and haven't seen any positive or negative effect. I can see where you're coming from this with this answer. Thanks amy

Comment: Just to note that the `allowQuotedStrings` is set to `true` by default via the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.ml.data.textloader.createfrom?view=ml-dotnet#Microsoft_ML_Data_TextLoader_CreateFrom__1_System_Boolean_System_Char_System_Boolean_System_Boolean_System_Boolean_). Defintely worth the try, though. You never know :p

Answer (score -1):

There is bad formated value on 252 and 253 rows. May me there fields wich contains the delimiter charachter.
If you post code or sample data we can be more precise.

Comment: I've added my code to the question. Ill check if there are any delimiter characters